# $form->bind change my $entity values

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a problem with my bind method, i don't think it's a normal behavior.
My $entity variable loose the property set earlier after the bind method of the form.

> $entity = $em->getRepository('XX:YY')->findOne();
>   var_dump($entity); *//dispaly entity params with param2 null*
>
> $entity->setParam2('hello');
>   var_dump($entity); *//dispaly entity params with param2 'hello'*
>
> $editForm = $this->createForm(new YYFormType($em), $entity);
>   var_dump($entity); *//dispaly entity params with param2 'hello'*
>
> $editForm->bind($request);
>    var_dump($entity); *//dispaly entity params with param2 **null***

I don't understand why it do that.

it's like every changes on entity are done by reference.

Is it normal ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the value of param2 in request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It normally binds the given entity with the form values, given themselves by your request object.

If you do a

```
$yourForm = $this->createForm(new YYFormType($em), $entity);
$yourForm->bind(...);
```

action means you are "hydrating" your entity with the form values. In this case the param2 value in your form must be null too.

If it's the case, this behavior is a normal one.

If you perform the

```
$entity->setParam2('hello');
```

after the

```
$yourForm->bind(...);
```

then your param2 should now be "hello".